# Segmentation fault on my class function

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

So I'm getting a segmentation fault on my function here and I'm not sure how to correct it. Any clues as to how I would go about it?
I'm including my classes and then the function below to give an idea of what I have.
Thanks!

```
template <typename T>
class Element{
private:
  Element *next_ = nullptr;
  string name_ = "";
  T color_ = T();

public:
  Element()=default;
  Element(string name, T d) : next_(nullptr), name_(name), color_(d){};
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Element& n){


    out << n.name_ << ":" << n.color_;
    return out;

  }
  friend class PAL<T>;
};


template<typename T>
class PAL{
private:
  Element<T> *back_ = nullptr;
  Element<T> *front_ = nullptr;
  void print_list(ostream& out);  
public:
  PAL()=default;
  PAL(Element<T> n) : back_(&n), front_(&n) {};
  PAL(string n, T d);
  PAL(const PAL&);
  PAL& operator=(PAL);
  ~PAL();
  void add(Element<T> &n);
  void add(string name, T dat);
  pair<Element<T>*, Element<T>*> find(string name);    
  pair<Element<T>*, Element<T>*> find(Element<T> &n);
  void move_forward1(Element<T> &n);
  void move_to_front(Element<T> &n);  
  void move_back1(Element<T> &n);
  void move_to_back(Element<T> &n);  

  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, PAL<T>& sl){
    sl.print_list(out);
    return out;
  };
};

template<typename T>
pair<Element<T>*, Element<T>*> PAL<T>::find(string name){
    pair<Element<T>*, Element<T>*> *result (nullptr);
    Element<T>* x = nullptr;
    Element<T>* y = nullptr;
    for (Element<T> *n = back_; n != nullptr; n = n -> next_){
        if (n -> name_ == name){
            x = n;
            cout << x;
            break;
        }
        y = n;
    }
    result -> first = x;
    result -> second = y;
    return *result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pair<Element<T>*, Element<T>*> *result (nullptr);
```

followed by

```
result -> first = x;
result -> second = y;
return *result;
```

is a problem.

You haven't allocated memory for `result` and proceeded to use it as though it points to a valid object.

Simplify it. Remove `result` altogether and change the `return` statement to:

```
return {x, y};
```

Comment: God speed R Sahu.

Comment: @javaLover, Ha.

Comment: aha! Thanks you :)